# How to fix error caused by libmysqlclient.15.dylib not being loaded?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've upgraded to Rails 2.2.2 and installed the MySQL 2.7 gem and am seeing this error when I try to run a migration or start the server:

```
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
```

What's the fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others.

I found the fix [here](http://installingcats.com/2007/12/13/mysql-ruby-gem-install-problem-on-mac-os-x-leopard/).

Run:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/mysql.bundle
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I had to change the order here (install_name_tool -change [old] [new]), but it worked for me too.

Comment: Didn't work for me, even when I changed the 15 to 18. Sytse's solution did work, though I have no idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 4):

I had to remove the directory from the old references:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle

sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib 
    /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/mysql.bundle
```

Comment: This one worked for me, unlike Gabe Hollombe's solution. No idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

Using sudo can often lead to unexpected issues. What worked for me was uninstalling the mysql2 gem and reinstalling it.

`gem uninstall mysql2`
`bundle`

Answer (score 1):

If Gabe Hollombe solution doesn't works then try this

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.15.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle

sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.15.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.15.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/mysql.bundle
```