# Trying to access my ruby project- LoadError pertaining to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to access my first ruby project. After navigating to the proper directory and typing:

> $ rails server

I get the following error message:

> /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
>
>     Referenced from: /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>
>     Reason: image not found - /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in`'
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`block in require'
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require' 
>       from /Users/Rozey/Sites/first_project/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in`block in '
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
>
>       from /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

I had previously installed the mysql2 gem using RVM. I know there is probably a simple fix but I'm new to this, so I appreciate your help.

Some extra information:

> Rozey$ which ruby
>   /Users/Rozey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
>   Rozey$ which mysql
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: How have you installed MySQL, from source or brew or ...?

Comment: From http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ using the 64-bit DMG option. I also used RVM to install the mysql gem.

Comment: Alright, I don't have a fix for your specific problem at hand then, but the solution is most likely the `install_name_tool` utility which fixed similar issues I've had with Gentoo Prefix in the past.

Comment: thanks @lebreeze and @svoop for the suggestions. I tried the following but an still getting the same error    sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [How to fix "dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517976/how-to-fix-dlopen-library-ruby-gems-1-8-gems-mysql-2-7-lib-mysql-bundle-9-li)

It looks like it could be a similar issue

Comment: Thanks @lebreeze and @svoop for suggesting the correct technique. I was having troubles entering the correct paths so I went into the chat room at http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm where @esparkman proposed the following solution. It worked! 

>sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Users/Rozey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

then

>sudo ln /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Answer (score 3):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"
```

Dropped that in bash.profile and worked like a charm

Comment: I had the same problem as the question using the mysql2 gem. This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above and none of it worked.  I found this on another page [Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib error when trying to run 'rails server' on OS X 10.6 with mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv) and it worked like a charm:

> **sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib**