# Use Mysql2 for Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I try to run rails S and get the following error.

```
 /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require':     dlopen(/Users/KaushiK/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/KaushiK/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
from /Users/ME/Desktop/MyRailProjects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I followed a previous thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394873/trying-to-access-my-ruby-project-loaderror-pertaining-to-mysql) and wrote the following,

```
 sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10- osx10.7-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.8/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Which did nothing. I mean it went through then i wrote this.

```
sudo ln /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

When i type this it says

```
 ln: /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why. and I cant see the files and directories even though i enabled view hidden files.  I do not know how to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you absolutely have to use Oracle's broken MySQL 5.5 packages, honestly the easiest solution is to drop back down to 5.1. That said...

When you say install_name tool "did nothing," what do you mean? Did you try building the gem again after that? Giving the appearance of "doing nothing" is the standard state of success for UNIX tools.

Re: the ln, even the newest releases are still tagged 10.6. Unless you've renamed the MySQL directory yourself, it's mysql-5.5.10-osx10.**6**-x86_64.

Comment: Well what i meant was when i wrote this command there was no acknowledgement or anything. Anyhow i have changed the the 10.7 to 10.6 and then when i run the two commands it works but still the initial error persists. Any ideas about how that is solved? Would using 5.1 solve the issue?